# How can I make this modal dialog open on page load?

Tags: html, jquery, modal-dialog

I am installing [this modal dialog](https://jquerymodal.com/) on a client's website, with practically no modifications.

However, I could not find how to make the modal dialog display on page load in the documentation.

Right now it just says:

```
<!-- Link to open the modal -->
<p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>
```

But I am sure there is a way to make it just open on load.

I am using a hosted version of jQuery (jquery.min.js, jquery.modal.min.js) so I'm not trying to add/edit code in the JS file.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal Method 2: Manually:

```
$(function() {
  $('#login-form').modal();
});
```

Comment: I think why I am confused is because I am not using my JS library, just calling the one referenced (jquery.modal). Maybe I need to search there for the right command to call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create on your html a div like this:

```
<div ng-include="'/Somepast/busyModal.html'" ng-show="isLoading"></div>
<div> after load</div>
```

Then in your javascript you create:

```
function init() {
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    SomeFunction().then(function (data) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    }, onError);
};
```

that's it.

Comment: Original question didn't ask for AngularJS but pure JQuery and HTML

Comment: I am not adding code to the jQuery if possible, just pulling commands from the one included